# 550 From header does not match login user

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm trying to use Migadu as an email host for my server but when I test postfix using sendmail I get the error

> 550 From header does not match login user

I have these settings in main.cf

```
relayhost = [smtp.migadu.com]:587
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

And I have this in my sasl_passwd file

```
[smtp.migadu.com]:587    postmaster@mydomain.com:password
```

Can someone help me find out what's causing the error?

Comment: Have you tried asking Migado support

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out for anyone still looking ...

In Laravel's **mail.php** config file, find the section on the **Global "From" Address**.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

You have to change **hello@example.com** to your email login for **migadu**. It worked for me after that.